# 'The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects.'

Tags: exception, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

See the code below. Seems I have this problem yet it is the same instance of the DbContext that created the collections.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5Nyk.png)

Comment: You missed adding the code.

Comment: Please add a code sample.

Comment: Yes I see that. I thought I did. I will add now.

Comment: Click on the "enter Image Descrption here" link for the code.

Comment: As you can see this is a singleton instance. The DbContext is created in the private constructor. It loads the data fine, which is then dislayed in a gid control. If I edit the grid I get the exeption on the call to SaveChanges. As best I can tell there is only one instance of the DbContext ever created.